# Execute SSH commands on Cisco router. Codeigniter SSH library

Tags: codeigniter, ssh, cisco

I have a little problem. I'm using Codeigniter with SSH library written by Shuky (https://bitbucket.org/quicktips/codeigniter-ssh2-library/src/a444968345ba/SSH.php -- You can see the code by following this link).

Everything related with SSH works fine with other devices, but when I try to use this library and execute commands on Cisco devices, nothing happens (commands are not executed). I know that the connection is successful, but I can't execute any commands.

When I try to run and execute comands through SSH on Cisco devices I get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/SSH.php

Line Number: 128

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/SSH.php

Line Number: 129
```

In the library these lines look like this:

```
       /**
 * Get stream data
 *
 * @access privte
 * @return bool
 */
function _get_stream_data($stream) {
    stream_set_blocking( $stream, true );
    while( $buf = fread($stream,4096) ) {
        $this->data .= $buf.'~';
    }
    return TRUE;
}    



line 128 - stream_set_blocking( $stream, true );
line 129 - while( $buf = fread($stream,4096) ) {
```

Maybe you guys know where the problem is?

Thank you for your time and your answers!

Comment: How do you use the SSH class. Could you show some of your code? What is the `command` that you are trying to `execute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). The fact that it's currently supported not-withstanding, it also supports logging, which might assist you - or the author - in figuring out what's going on (assuming phpseclib has the same problem, which it might not!)

Answer (score 1):

The function _get_stream_data is used in the library in the following context:

```
  if($this->_is_conn()) {
        $stream = @ssh2_exec($this->conn_id, $command);
        return $this->_get_stream_data($stream);
  }
```

The `$stream` value returned by `ssh2_exec` is either a resource if ssh connection was successfully established or boolean **FALSE** in the case of error.

Unfortunately there is not much error handling you can do with the `ssh2` PECL library. The easiest is to output the value of `$command`. And execute the same command from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dmitri, but could you give me more details please?

Comment: I am afraid there is not much I can add, since I have no means to reproduce the problem. What I am saying is that the problem is not in `stream_set_blocking`, but in `ssh2_exec`.

Comment: But is it possible to add something to the library and make it work for cisco devices too?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command first

```
$this->ssh->execute($cmd);
```

You can then view the stream like this:

```
echo $this->ssh->data;
```